# Surface Area of $S =$ {$x^2+y^2+z^2=4, (x-1)^2+y^2\leq1$}

Tags: surface-integrals

Find the area of the following surface, $S =$ {$x^2+y^2+z^2=4, (x-1)^2+y^2\leq1$}?

How do I find a parameterization of the surface?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Start by giving the polar coordinates equation of the circle $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$. Now use cylindrical coordinates to parametrize $S$.